# В разница между командами hlt и pause? Что лучше использовать?

Tags: ассемблер, x86-64

hlt "останавливает" процессор до прихода прерывания, что снижает нагрузку. pause тоже "останавливает", но не могу найти конкретного описания. Коды у них разные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ух. Попробую ответить.

Основная идея, как я понял, в том, что **HLT** (halt) - останавливает логический 
процессор, освобождая доступ к общим ресурсам в физическом пакете, которыми могут воспользоваться все активные логические процессоры в этом же пакете.

А **PAUSE** используется для того чтобы повысить производительность в процессорах с технологией Hyper-Threading. Суть в том что код, который ожидает освобождения чего-либо путем обращения к семафору, находится в wait цикле. Если код выйдет из цикла и обнаружит, что порядок в памяти нарушен (memory order violation), процессор просто сбросит конвейер (pipeline flush). Это приведет к проседанию производительности в целом. **PAUSE** таким образом нужен для того, чтобы подсказать процессору что кодовая последовательность является wait циклом, и помогает избежать memory order violation и pipeline flush. Также эта инструкция дает какие-то бонусы в энергопотреблении, но я не вчитывался.

Можете почитать еще тут: https://xem.github.io/minix86/manual/intel-x86-and-64-manual-vol3/o_fe12b1e2a880e0ce-302.html

Comment: Вкратце: pause - тормозит поток, hlt - тормозил логический процессор. Если несколько потоков, то лучше pause, иначе не имеет разницы.

Comment: @Adokenai Нуу, hlt же освобождает ресурсы в пакете для других логических процессоров? Разве они (другие логические процессоры) не могут быть из другого процесса?

Comment: речь про аппаратные потоки. Hyper-Threading как бы намекает. То есть, если есть два ядра с НТ, или 4 потока, то hlt остановить 1 ядро, то есть останется 2 потока второго, а pause остановит только поток и останется 3 потока.